# Geting values from php into c# web service

Tags: c#, php

I've got a page with a questionary. Then I get the values from the questionary and send the values(array) to my c# web service. My question is, how do I GET each value from the variables in the array into variables in the c# web service?

In my web service I got something like:

```
   [WebMethod]
    public string GetDados(int a, int b)
    {

        return "stuff com " + (a+b).toString();
    }
```

Where, the Variables **a** and **b** are values from the variables sent by the PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you are going to be able to get a PHP application and C# application to work together is by building an API into the C# application that the PHP application is able to consume or utilizing some sort of socket based RPC framework. There is no way to directly inject the PHP code in the C# web service.